# How to show name of selected file on a GUI as a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, file-io, awt, java-io

I am Trying to select a file using showOpenDialog and I want to set name of selected file as a JLabel on my GUI. 
I wrote this code but it is not working.. can anyone please tell me the right method?

```
    b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(fc);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                String fileName= file.getName();
                l6 = new JLabel(fileName);
                l6.setBounds(50, 315, 70, 20);
                p.add(l6);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: "I wrote this code but it is not working" - specifically what is not working? Are you getting exceptions? If not, is your GUI showing anything at all?  Be more specific.

Comment: @splungebob it is not showing the JLabel l6 after selecting file, i mean it is showing everything else but l6

Comment: For further help you need to provide an SSCCE: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @splungebob how is my question not fitting in SSCCE? other people seem to get it..

Comment: @OP: Other people? Exactly one person took an educated guess and it happened to help you. Great. Don't expect this to be the norm, however. And as far as your post being an SSCCE, you must not know what the acronym stands for. A code-snippet is not a self-contained, compilable example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new `JLabel` is not appearing as you would need to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` to update the container to account for the newly added component.

From your use of `setBounds`, it appears you are using absolute positioning (If not, a layout manager will pay no heed to this call). *Always* better to use a [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for positioning & sizing components..

You could simply call `setText` on an existing `JLabel` instead of adding a new one to the container:

```
b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(fc);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            String fileName = file.getName();
            l6.setText(fileName);
        }
    }
});
```